# Bad socket id, Stream closed error + blackberry socket connection

Tags: sockets, blackberry, connection

I am writing a program in blackberry curve 9300 using socketConnection. I get stream closed/bad socket id error when I try to read the inputstream.
Can you suggest me what could be the issue.

```
String url = Constants.SOCKET + serverIp + Constants.COLON + serverPort + UserInfo.getConnectionType();

//connection open
socketConne`enter code here`ction = (SocketConnection) Connector.open(url, Connector.READ_WRITE,true);

socketConnection.setSocketOption(SocketConnection.DELAY, 0);
socketConnection.setSocketOption(SocketConnection.KEEPALIVE, 1);
socketConnection.setSocketOption(SocketConnection.RCVBUF, 16834);
socketConnection.setSocketOption(SocketConnection.LINGER, 10);

outputStream = socketConnection.openDataOutputStream();

//Output stream deligated to Sender Object to send the command
sender = new Sender(outputStream);
sender.send(command);
inputStream = socketConnection.openDataInputStream();

//read inputstream
while (tobeRead < toRead && retryCount < 5) {
    try {
        if ((toRead - tobeRead) > 8192) {
            readBufferLength = 8192;
        } else {
            readBufferLength = (toRead - tobeRead);
        }
        buffer = new byte[readBufferLength + 1];

        bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, readBufferLength);
        sb.append(new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
        tobeRead += bytesRead;
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    } catch (Exception cce) {
    }
}
```

say if number of bytes to read is 5192. I get say 2123 bytes then it iterates the loop, next time while reading it fails. I run this in seperate thread. I use WIFI network for connectivity

Comment: How do you know you need to read 5192 bytes? Where do you get the `tobeRead` value?

Comment: Didn't understand. Did you read full buffer during first iteration. Or you get it partly filled? Also small optimization - no needs to create buffer each time. Create it once and reuse every iteration.

Comment: From server, I get size of the stream \n and actual stream, so I read the size,  I create the buffer with 8192 size and loop until I get complete data. if the size is less than 8192, I read it in one go. Is it issue with blackberry device to read complete data. The same thing works fine in simulator